# How does inverse of logistic function produces "linear relationship", (so we can use least-squares)

Tags: time-series, logistic-regression, logistic

I am reading about time-series analysis [in "A First Course on
Time Series Analysis"](https://www.mathematik.uni-wuerzburg.de/fileadmin/10040800/user_upload/time_series/the_book/2012-August-01-times.pdf).  The book reviews the [logistic function ($f_{log}(t)$)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function)  (more on the special logistic function [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/204484/what-are-the-differences-between-logistic-function-and-sigmoid-function/415544#comment1153523_415544) and [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hois2F0bSxU&t=15s)).

Part 1.6 (PDF page 16; book page 8; screenshot below) explains how the *inverse of the logistic function* ($1/f_{log}(t)$) produces a linear relationship; so that "it can serve as a basis for estimating the parameters $β_1$, $β_2$, $β_3$ by an appropriate linear least squares approach"

I don't understand the last sentence:

> This means that there is a linear relationship among $1/f_{log}(t)$.

[image: mathematical proof showing how the inverse of logistic function has a linear relationship]

I specifically don't understand how the inverse of a logistic function, can produce a "linear relationship"; it doesn't look like a "straight line" when I graph it:

```
import math
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

get_logistic = lambda b1, b2, b3: lambda x: (b3/(1+b2*np.exp(-b1*x)))

x = np.linspace(-10,10)
y = get_logistic(1,1,1)(x)

plt.plot(x,y)
plt.show()
plt.plot(x,1/y)
plt.show()
```

[image: two graphs, the first of a logsitic function, the second of the inverse of a logistic function]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's true, the function $1/f_{log}(t)$ is not linear, in other words there is not a linear relationship between $t$ and $1/f_{log}(t)$ but that's not what the author meant; the the important word is "among";

> This means that there is a linear relationship among $1/f_{log}(t)$.

Note the end of the equations in the OP:

$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{1}{f_{log}(t)} &=... \\
\frac{1}{f_{log}(t)} &= a + \frac{b}{f_{log}(t-1)} \\
\end{aligned}
$$

So there are relationship among the `y` values (the output of the function); specifically, there is a linear relationship between $1/f_{log}(t-1)$ and $1/f_{log}(t)$, where $a$ is the linear "y-intercept" and $b$ is the linear "slope".

So we can change the code to `plt.plot(1/y_of_x_minus_1, 1/y)`, and we will see a straight line:

```
import math
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

get_logistic = lambda b1, b2, b3: lambda x: (b3/(1+b2*np.exp(-b1*x)))

logistic_args = (1,1,1)
logistic_function = get_logistic(*logistic_args)

x = np.linspace(-10,10)
x_minus_1 = x-1

y = logistic_function(x)
y_of_x_minus_1 = logistic_function(x_minus_1)

plt.plot(1/y_of_x_minus_1, 1/y)
plt.show()
pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'x_less_1': x_minus_1, 'y_for_x_less_1': 1/y_of_x_minus_1, 'y': 1/y})
```

Notice the straight line:
[image: linear_relationship_among_y_and_y_of_x_minus_1]

**EDIT**

The linear relationship *among* $y$ values helps us estimate the parameters for the logistic function, using a linear least squares approach:

> This (linear relationship) can serve as a basis for estimating the parameters $β_1, β_2, β_3$ by an appropriate linear least squares approach, see Exercises 1.2 and 1.3.

And the exercise 1.2 asks:

> Then we have the linear regression model
> $z_t = a + bz_{t−1} + ε_t$ , where $ε_t$ is the error variable. Compute the least squares estimates $\hat{a}$, $\hat{b}$

And the [least-squares formula for the general case of $y=β_0+β_1x+ε$ goes like this](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmd/section4/pmd431.htm) (note: beta's mean something different than the three beta's of logistic function, above) (same formulas shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=233&v=y5INeKvfpcQ&feature=emb_logo) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Simple_linear_regression_model))

> $\hat{\beta}_1 = \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})}{\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})^2}$
>
> $\hat{\beta}_0 = \bar{y} - \hat{\beta}_1\bar{x}$

I will try to come back and edit the answer to demonstrate how the linear relationship lets us solve for $\hat{\beta_0}$ and $\hat{\beta_1}$ (aka $\hat{a}$ and $\hat{b}$), which lets us figure out the 3 beta's of the logistic function, as suggested in the exercise 1.2:

> Compute the least squares estimates $\hat{a}$, $\hat{b}$ of $a$, $b$ and motivate the estimates $\hat{β_1}:= −log(\hat{b})$, $\hat{β_3} := (1 − exp(−\hat{β}_1))/\hat{a}$ as well as $\hat{β_2} := ...$

For an exercise I tried to change the [`itl.nist.gov` form](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/pmd/section4/pmd431.htm) ....

> $\sum_{i=1}^{n} (x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})$

...to the [wikipedia form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares#Simple_linear_regression_model)...

> $\sum x_i y_i - \frac{1}{n} \sum x_i \sum y_i$

### Starting like this...

$\sum (x_i-\bar{x})(y_i-\bar{y})$

...then, [multiply the binomials](https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/polynomials-multiplying.html)...

$\sum (x_iy_i - x_i\bar{y} - y_i\bar{x} + \bar{x}\bar{y})$

...then, [distributing the sum](https://mathlesstraveled.com/2017/03/18/sigma-notation-ninja-tricks-2-splitting-sums/)...

$\sum x_iy_i - \sum x_i\bar{y} - \sum y_i\bar{x} + \sum \bar{x}\bar{y}$

...and because it sums over all $n$ values ($\sum_{i=1}^{n}$), the same $n$ values used for the means/expected values of $x$ and $y$ ($\hat{x}$, and $\hat{y}$) ...

$\sum x_iy_i - \sum x_i\bar{y} - \sum y_i\bar{x} + n \bar{x}\bar{y}$

... then, we transform $n\bar{x}$ into $n \frac{\sum{x_i}}{n}$ then into $\sum x_i$ (we could instead transform the $n\bar{y}$; would reach the same end result)...

$\sum x_iy_i - \sum x_i\bar{y} - \sum y_i\bar{x} + \sum x_i\bar{y}$

... then two terms will cancel....

$\sum x_iy_i  - \sum y_i\bar{x} $

... then, the wikipedia form (which is almost the covariance, aka the $ 
 \text{Cov}[x,y]$ (just imagine another $\frac{1}{n}$ distributed among the terms)....

$\sum x_iy_i  - \frac{1}{n}\sum y_i\sum x_i $